# Commerce Search API with Custom Search Form

Tags: commerce, search

I have a search form with multiple fields on my front page. After clicking on submit button,  user would be routed to search result page. The user fills out the form, clicks on a 'Search' button, and the browser replaces the front page with a results page. (Ideally, a Commerce search view). On search result page, all facets blocks are enabled.

I have created a page using Views exposed filter for front page and I am getting result as per filters. But I am not able to map that search filters with my facet search blocks on result page. Is there any way to do that ?

Another way I tried is created a custom form but not sure how to build URL so that user would be redirected to Search result page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by creating a custom form and in submit hook, I have redirected user to my search result page using below code.

```
if (isset($form_state['values']['brand']) &&  $form_state['values']['brand'] != '') {
      $element[0] = 'field_product%3Afield_brand:'. $form_state['values']['brand'];
      $cnt++;
    }

    $elements = serialize(array('f' => $element));

    $form_state['redirect'] = array('search/parts/results', array('query' => unserialize($elements)));
```

I didn't find any better solution as my display widget types are different for both the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same faceted search block on front page too. You can invoke the faceted search block on front page.

Comment: But Format of my search blocks are different. Like on front page I want dropdown and in result page I want checkboxes for same facet.

Comment: Thanks Parvin for ur suggestion. It helped me to find out the way.

Comment: Adoshi, If solution works for you, please mark this as answer. It will be helpful for someone else.